# Is there something like xargs which pipes data instead of using arguments?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, xargs

`xargs` is great if you have a command that accepts its input via command line arguments, but it's not nearly as useful if you have a command that accepts its input via stdin.

What I've seen suggested for situations sort of like this would be to use `tee` to duplicate the lines to several downstream processes, like this:

```sh
producer | tee >(consumer0 >out0) >(consumer1 >out1) >(consumer2 >out2) | consumer3 >out3;
cat out* | next-stage-of-pipeline
```

This has the disadvantage of all consumers receiving all lines produced, and the assumption appears to be that `consumer{0..3}` are different processes. If I need each consumer to be the same, and process part of the input (for example, to parallelize a sequential consumer), it doesn't work as well.

What I'm looking for is something that, like `xargs`, allows splitting up the work between multiple instances of the same consumer, then combining the input and continuing processing. The way the output is combined should mimic `xargs`, so no guarantee about the order of lines, but two lines won't get spliced together (ex: "Hello Fred" and "Hello George" might come out in any order, but you wouldn't see "HHello GeoFregedello").

The primary use for something like this would be processing large amounts of data, where the startup delay for the consumers would be noticeable if one were spun up for each line of the input. If `consumer` were inexpensive to start up I'd simply wrap it in a small shell script which pipes it's arguments into `consumer` and call that with `xargs`.

At least for the use case I have in mind, the producer would be grabbing a bunch of data from an internal service, after which the consumers would need to transform that data and make some API calls. So the producer and consumers are both going to be long running processes, and running the API calls in parallel is really going to speed things up.

Something like this would be ideal, but I've been unable to find anything that does this:

```sh
producer | ??? -P20 consumer | next-stage-of-pipeline
```

Is there a command-line tool which would provide this functionality?

Comment: How do you propose to split the input? line by line round robin? First 1/20th to consumer0, next 1/20th to consumer1, ...? How is output to be combined?

Comment: Ideally it'd be configurable, realistically round-robin is the easiest to implement and what I'd expect would probably be available if such a tool exists (I think this is how xargs splits the input into arguments). To behave in a reasonable way in the presence of large input, I'd expect the output to provide no guarantees other than the lines won't be mingled (the option for null delimiting would be nice) when emitted as the tools stdout (basically how xargs behaves)

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you just `xargs -P20 bash -c 'consumer <<<"$1"' --` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk that works if `consumer` is quick to spin up, but it's less that ideal if you're piping into something written in a language like Java which has both a startup cost, and tends to get faster the longer it's run.

Comment: @Morgen to avoid additional confusion, can you clarify if 'producer ' is 'expensive' (time, memory, slow startup, etc,), and the amount of data expected to be produced. Is it important to have consumer/producers run in parallel ?

Comment: Sure, @dash-o. Check the updated description for details, but the TL;DR is that the processor is long-running and will load a non-trivial amount of data. Processing that as quickly as possible is highly desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `GNU Paralell` might do what you're looking for.

```
producer | parallel consumer | next command in pipeline
```

edit: I didn't *quite* understand the problem until I started playing with `parallel`. Parallel can take a function as a consumer, and you can play with streams inside that function.

e.g.

```
consumer () 
{ 
    echo "$@" | awk '{print $2}'
}
export -f consumer
for i in {1..30}; do echo "foo $i bar"; done | parallel consumer
```

edit 2:

You can use the `--pipe` option, which pipes data to the consumer. The `-q` argument puts shell quotes around the consumer:

```
for i in {1..30}; do echo "foo $i bar"; done | parallel --pipe -q awk '{print $2}'
```

Bonuses:

1. `parallel` will run jobs on sequential processors. If you have 8 cores and 16 consumers, each core will get 2 consumers (this is configurable)
2. `parallel` can run across multiple machines on the network, as long as it can `ssh` to them without being prompted for a password (e.g. using `ssh-agent`).

Comment: I'm going to read up on this a bit more, it sounds really promising.

Answer (score 1):

> splitting up the work between multiple instances of the same consumer

This could be done at the consumer side of `xargs`.

Ex:

```
consumer() {
   consumer$(($RANDOM % 4)) "$@"
}
export -f consumer
producer | xargs -P20 bash -c consumer --
```

Will pick a random consumer.

The:

```
consumer() {
   seq 4 |
   xargs -i{} consumer{} "$@"
}
export -f consumer
producer | xargs -P20 bash -c consumer --
```

Will run the input for each consumer.

Anyway, you should get the idea.

And for your tee, it's easy to do it without any temp files:

```
consumer() { sed "s/^/$1: /"; }
producer() { seq 3; }
next-stage-of-pipeline() { sed "s/^/Result: /"; }
producer |
{ tee >(consumer 0 >&10) >(consumer 1 >&11) >(consumer 2 >&12) | consumer 3 >&14 ;} 10>&1 11>&1 12>&1 14>&1 | 
next-stage-of-pipeline
```

If you need ex. to split the input in 4 for each consumer, it's still easy enough to do:

```
filter() { awk -vN="$1" '(NR + N) % 4 == 1'
producer |
{ tee >(
     filter 1 | consumer 0 >&10
) >(
     filter 2 | consumer 1 >&11
) >(
     filter 3 | consumer 2 >&12
) | 
     filter 4 | consumer 3 >&14 
;} 10>&1 11>&1 12>&1 14>&1 | 
next-stage-of-pipeline
```

Comment: I think there's a caveat that only buffered writes are guaranteed to be atomic on POSIX systems and only if smaller than PIPE_BUF (eg. stderr is not buffered by default)

Comment: While I like that this is a pure shell solution, it doesn't scale well to ~20 consumers (easy to make typos when you have to repeat that much nearly-identical code)

Comment: The `>( ... )` doesn't scale and never scaled ok. You can do pipes in `awk` tho, so you could try that. Except for that, I think we will have to write our own tool to do that. But does ex. the last code snippet do what you have in mind? Split the stream on 4 even streams and pipe it to each consumer in parallel?

Comment: Yes, it does exactly what I'm looking for. I'm just holding off on accepting in the hope that a tool exists that already does this.

Comment: I _think_ it could be scripted in pure bash - but it would be pain to handle errors and it would be very slow. A C program would be best. It really looks like it should work like ex. "haproxy with multiple backends" - you get a request, you forward to request to one of many backends, and on the way you track how many connections there are to the backend, etc. I believe I could be interested in such a tool, so well, keep the question open, maybe someone will come along with such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel can chop up standard input to the same command:

```
... | parallel --pipe consumer
```

It chops by default on `\n` with a block size around 1 MB. This can be changed with `--recstart`/`--recend` and `--block`.

If the input is a file, this is even faster:

```
parallel -a bigfile --pipepart --block -1 consumer
```

This will find the size of `bigfile` and split that into one block for each CPU thread. This is done on-the-fly - so no temporary files are created.

Chapter 9 of https://zenodo.org/record/1146014 covers this in detail.

But if you really want the whole input piped to different consumers, GNU Parallel can do that, too:

```
# Pipe 1..10 to consumer-a..z
seq 10 | parallel --pipe --tee 'echo consumer-{}; cat' ::: {a..z}
```